# Can I use a battery isolator and have a lithium battery and lead acid battery charge off of the same alternator?

Tags: battery

The lead acid battery is for a high current application (650 amp @ 3 min max) and the lithium is a house battery. The lithium is a 12.8v nominal. It charges to 14.6v then the BMS cuts off incoming charge. The resting charge is 13.2-13.4v. The lead acid is a standard 12v nominal. The resting charge is 12.8v. This is a 2 battery isolator. Does it matter which terminal a battery is connected to? Does the isolator give charge preference to one post over the other?

Comment: Can’t say without details of the isolator... a piece of wire moved between two nails would work but that will be manual...

Comment: the battery isolator is a Promariner ProIsoCharge 120 1-3. The alternator is a Balmer 100A that is set to output 14.6v. The lead acid is AGM 4D, the lithium is 400 Ah with 200 amp BMS.

Comment: I had expected you to provide the link to the data sheet... But in the absence I will suugest you need to make sure the device is “make before break” otherwise you may end up with expensive damage.

Comment: the link to the manual and data sheet is http://www.promariner.com/en/library.  you have to drill down the menu and open the pdf                                              
 v   Battery Isolator Manuals
 Battery Isolator Manual
 ProIsoCharge Manual

Comment: what exactly is 'make before break' mean

Comment: It means when switching from one battery to the other that there is no point when neither battery is connected - an alternator can suffer damage if not connected to a battery.